# Text to Speech framework for iOS with kids voice

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to build a kids game using Swift. I want to use text to speech API in my app, but all the API which I came through were either male or female robot kind of voice. Is there any API available which converts text to speech with kids voice or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the standard `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and increase the pitch:

```
import AVFoundation

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hi, uh.. I'm a.. um kid!" )
utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.3 // or whatever value you find works well 
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: Coooool ! `2` was pitch-perfect for me ;)